# How to decrypt an encrypted data came from server with AES decryption?

Tags: swift, encryption, aes, urlsession

I'm working on a project that'll open PDF books inside application. I'm fetching the books from the server and they're coming as locked pdf pages and I'm also fetching each pages' password with another API.

The problem is, the list of passwords are coming as AES encrypted. I can not decrypt them properly. I don't know what am I missing. My code is below. Waiting for your answers. Thank you :) (I'm using CrytoSwift library)

(I'm taking key and iv with an another function and keeping them in two different variables.)

```
import CryptoSwift

var myEncryptedData : String = ""
var key32 : String = ""
var iv16: String = ""


 func decryptData() {

        do {
            let aes = try AES(key: Array(key32.utf8), blockMode: CBC(iv: Array(iv16.utf8)), padding: .pkcs7)
            let ciphertext = try aes.decrypt(myEncryptedData.bytes)
            print(String(data: Data(ciphertext), encoding: .utf8));
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I tried to decrypt encryptedString with AES decryption by using CryptoSwift library but I couldn't fetch the data that I expected.

Comment: Can you add the output from the `print` statements to the question as it will give a better idea of the problem.

Comment: `key: Array(key32.utf8)` : I am really doubtful the key is provided to you as a string whose bytes are the key (there must be lots of not-printable characters). It is much more probably hexadecimal or base64... How looks the key string ?

Comment: And the same for the IV : `iv: Array(iv16.utf8)`.

Comment: I just added let d = Data(base64Encoded: encryptedString) just below do and it worked. Thank you friends for answers

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code just below "do" and it worked

```
let d = Data(base64Encoded: encryptedString)
```

Working version is:

```
do {
    let d = Data(base64Encoded: encryptedString)
    let aes = try AES(key: Array(key32.utf8), blockMode: CBC(iv: Array(iv16.utf8)), padding: .pkcs7)
    let ciphertext = try aes.decrypt(d!.bytes)
    let stringCipherText = String(data: Data(ciphertext), encoding: .utf8)      
} catch {
 print(error)
}
```